# How to make a condition if a list length is plus one?

Tags: reactjs

What I'm trying to do is to set a hook state if in the list is added a new client.
To get the clients I use axios.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const clientParams =
      "userName=" +
      currentUser
      "clientId=" +
      currentClient
    setClientlist([]);
    axios
    .get(process.env.REACT_API_URL + clientParams)
    .then((response) => {

      let newListClient = response.data.map(function (client) {
        return {
          ...client,
          id: client.id,
          name: client.name,
          gender: client.client.gender
        };
      });
        setClientlist(newListClient);

        if (newListItem.length + 1 > newListItem.length){
          console.log('test')
        }
      })
       
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [count]);
```

So the idea is when a client is saved(which the save function is on another component), the length of the `newListClient` is added by 1, and since the length is more than the previous one, the condition will be executed.
The problem is that the `console.log('test')` is shown every time I reload or open the page.
What I want is the console to be shown when the length of the `newListItem` is added by 1.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Before you `set` the new array, capture the existing length in order to compare. Or, use the idea of a callback function by trying something like this: `setClientlist(prev => { if (prev.length < newListClient.length) {console.log('test')}; return newListClient; });`

Comment: Here `newListItem.length + 1 > newListItem.length` you are not comparing the previous length with the current you are just checking if the `current length of the array + 1 > current length of the array` which is of course always true.

Comment: @jsN00b it doesn't work, the console is shown when I render the page

Comment: Please try changing the condition to: `if (prev && prev.length > 0 && prev.length < newListClient.length) ` - this will ensure that when your existing array is empty, the `console` will not be shown.

Comment: @jsN00b now the console.log('test') is not shown

Comment: @jsN00b even when the length is changed

Answer (score 0):

It is rendering for the first time because on first render everthing is undefined and so undefined + 1 > undefined is true. And when the values are updated by axios it is true as well ( this time with live data ). I thing changing the condition to the following will work.

```
if ( newListItem && newListItem?.length + 1 > newListItem?.length){
          console.log('test')
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I render the page, the console is shown

Comment: Ok then, save the previous length in state ( other then the one you have right now ) and them compare the lengths now  because @mushroomator comment is valid too.